# javascript setting height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, height

I am trying to do very simple thing, setting the height of div depends on what the height is.
So when the site load the height is 45px, after clicking in button height is 100px. After the next click I want my height back to 45px. I am using jQuery, the code is below:
http://codepen.io/zlyfenek/pen/pAcaw
Thanks for any help, as I am new to jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.toggleClass()` function of jQuery.

```
$(function(){
    $('.yourButton').click(function(){
       $('.yourDiv').toggleClass('big');
    });
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/FYyU6/

## Note:

Your `big` css class should come after your small class `Order Matters`.

Answer (score 1):

change `$("button").one` to `$("button").on`

Answer (score 0):

You should just have a class that sets the height to 100px, and then toggle it when you click on the button:

```
.opened { height: 100px; }

$("button").on("click", function() {
    $(".con_b").toggleClass("opened");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function showHeight(ele, h) {
$("div").text("The height for the " + ele +
" is " + h + "px.");
}

// use .on instead of .one, .one will online listen for a click one time, 
// so your second click will not be seen
$("button").on('click', function () {
  if ($(".con_b").height() == 45)
  {
    $(".con_b").height(100);
  }
  else
  {
    // show height and change height should be two different actions
    $('.con_b').height(45);
    showHeight(".con_b",$(".con_b").height());
  }

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function showHeight(ele, h) {
$("div").text("The height for the " + ele +
" is " + h + "px.");
}
$("button").on('click', function () {

  if ($(".con_b").height() == 45)
  {
    $(".con_b").height(100);
  }
  else
  {
    $(".con_b").height(45);
  }
```

its `$("button").on` not `$("button").one`